# Functions not changing the second time its called Jquery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm very new to JS and am trying to use functions call it later with different values. But the function seems to be applying the first value in both instances.

HTML

```
<div class="quality">
    <span id="quality" data-avgquality="28"></span>
</div>
<div class="cost">
    <span id="cost" data-avgcost="50"></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var qualitydata = $("#quality").attr("data-avgquality");
    var costdata = $("#cost").attr("data-avgcost");

    function loadData(id,data) 
    {
        $("#"+id+"").animate({ "width" : qualitydata+"%" }, 1500 );
    };

    loadData("quality",qualitydata);
    loadData("cost",costdata);

});
```

When I run this the data value for both comes as 28%.

Comment: I think you want to change `qualitydata` to `data`, inside the function.

Comment: Thanks Felix! that worked great! Silly me :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
function loadData(id,data) 
{
    $("#"+id+"").animate({ "width" : qualitydata+"%" }, 1500 );
};
```

to

```
function loadData(id,data) 
{
    $("#"+id+"").animate({ "width" : data +"%" }, 1500 );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In the loadData function you are ignoring the data argument and instead using the qualitydata variable from the enclosing function. i.e. where your have written:

```
$("#"+id+"").animate({ "width" : qualitydata+"%" }, 1500 );
```

I think you intended:

```
$("#"+id+"").animate({ "width" : data+"%" }, 1500 );
```